# How do I get the latest file in os.listdir('filepath')?

Tags: python, operating-system

I am looking for a way in which I can get the latest modified file in a folder using Python.

I have tried looking online for some solution but have had no luck so far with the OS module in Python. Maybe there is another module I should be using? This is my code so far:

```
os.listdir('G:\\Data\\Hotels\\FTP\\Hotel Data\\IDEAS')
```

From this list I want the last modified file. I am new to Python, so not sure what modules are available to me in order to look at the time modified for each file.

Comment: I am new to Python so none of that makes any sense to me! @DavidG I was hoping for more help on building on what I already have

Comment: simple answer: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/120500

Comment: Use `os.path.getmtime(path)` on each filename to get the last modified time.

Comment: @Sorath Your question's closed unfairly; here's one approach: `import os; from pathlib import Path; paths = [str(p) for p in Path(your_dir).iterdir() if p.is_file()]; paths.sort(key=os.path.getmtime); most_recent_path = paths[-1]`